# Autenticarse y devolver Token en consola

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, consola

Tengo que realizar un trabajo en el cual debo loguearme desde **consola** con un usuario 'precargado' o 'inventado' y que me devuelva **Token** de seguridad.

He realizado algunas pruebas desde MVC, obteniendo el **token**, buscando info y utilizando métodos IHttpActionResult en la Controladora, pero lo que he encontrado, si bien me ha servido porque me devuelve un token, no lo he podido entender.

¿Cómo podría obtener mi token desde mi clase Program y al autenticarme con un usuario precarcado, que me devuelva el mismo en un Console.WriteLine? No espero una solución solamente una pequeña ayuda para poder avanzar.

Tengo una clase Usuario que tiene:

```
public string usuario {get; set;}
public int clave {get; set;}
```

Esto es mi consola

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Login");
        Console.WriteLine("Usuario: ");
        string usuario = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Clave: ");
        string clave = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("      ");
        CustomerController.Autenticar();
//Aca me tira error porque .Autenticar no es estatico


    }
```

Y en mi controladora CustomerController tengo el razonamiento para devolver el token, mi intención es llamar al método desde consola

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("autenticar")]
    public IHttpActionResult Autenticar(loginRequest login)
    {
        if (login == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        //TODO: Validate credentials Correctly, this code is only for demo !!
        bool password = (login.Password == "123456");
        if (password)
        {
            var token = TokenGenerator.GenerateTokenJwt(login.Username);
            return Ok(token);
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

Comment: este link me sirvio para realizar lo que necesitas https://enmilocalfunciona.io/construyendo-una-web-api-rest-segura-con-json-web-token-en-net-parte-ii/ tambien el de rafael acosta tienen el usuario login en el webconfig http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/5/20/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-de-net-core

Comment: Gracias amigo el primer link es el que yo realice y que no entendi muy  bien del toddo. Hago los mismos pasos y ejecuto por POSTMAN.. Pero yo necesito pasarlo a mi realidad de CONSOLA. Y cuando llamo a un metodo del contolador me aparece un error,

Comment: cual es el código que hiciste en consola? estás creando un cliente desde consola?

Comment: publica el código donde hace autenticación, entre mas codigo publiques es mejor que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Desde mi consola quiero llamar al metodo de LoginController.Authenticate y ahi pasarle como parametros : user (console.readLine) y clave (console.readline)...  y que me retorne el TOKEN si el usuario y clave son correctos. 

Pero al llamar al action(authenticate), me da error porque no es estatico me parece... Pero lo pongo estatico y me saltan pila de errores en el mismo metodo O.o

Comment: @ger ahi actualice

Comment: Que es esto? CustomerController.. y si el servicio es web, deberias hacer alguna llamada web (que ahi no hay ninguna)...

Comment: @gbianchi CustomerController es una controladora que tiene metodos para autenticar y que devuelva un TOKEN si el usuario y clave son correctos. Mi intencion es pasar ese razonamiento e implementarlo por consola. Porque por postman me funciona bien pero no es el fin.

Comment: No importa desde lo llames, la llamada tiene que ser a una URL, porque ese controlador esta dentro de una web.. Todo esa parte falta en tu programa de consola...

Comment: @gbianchi Ah claro, seria como una llamada de ajax hacia el controlador pero sin utilizar ajax no? porque es desde c# ? que alternativa podria usar en ves de ajax?

Comment: cualquier tipo de objeto que te permita hacer una llamada web. Investiga sobre eso.. Tenes que hacer un post a esa URL

Comment: Dale muchas gracias no me había dado cuenta de esto.

Comment: Tambien se puede pasar el codigo de autenticacion a otra clase ServicioSeguridad de esta manera se puede invocar directamente usando console para datos de entrada sin necesidad del llamado al controlador